# Toolbar as action bar in Fragment

Tags: java, android

In my app, I use NoActionBar style, and I want to add action Bar to the one of my fragment.

In Activity I can do this like:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**How do this in fragment ?**

I tried so:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_app_bar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(actionBar);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training, container, false);

    }
```

But it doesn't work.

**UPD** 
I think the problem in this line:

```js
Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_app_bar);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
```

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by doesn't work? Does the bar just not appear? Are there any errors?

Comment: Bar just not appear... It mean that the toolbar (my_app_bar from fragment layout) appears. But this toolbar is not filled with items from main_menu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Old question)), should be:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_app_bar);
     //((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training, container, false);

     View v = inflater.inflate(r.layout.fragment_training, container, false);
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findviewbyid(r.id.my_app_bar);
     ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to,

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle();
```

These 2 links will be helpful for you,
[Set up toolbar as actionbar in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030183/set-up-toolbar-as-actionbar-in-fragment)

[How to get Toolbar from fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998455/how-to-get-toolbar-from-fragment)

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is set subtitle mean? just set text?